# Localhost en rails no muestra el CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ya enlace el css con el html pero aun asi la pagina no muestra los ajuste del css, solo el html... estoy trabajando con rails.

[image: este es la dirección del código C:\Users\BALARAMA\Desktop\boomerang\hello_world\hello_world\app\views\welcome]

Comment: No se mucho de rails, pero algo parecido con un archivo scss me paso en IIS había una configuración que se hacia en el server donde estaba todas las extensiones de archivo permitidas, una lista bien larga y no estaba .scss, le agregué salte de un pie.

Answer (score 1):

Has editado `index.html.erb` como si fuese tu layout principal. Todo ese código debería ir en `application.html.erb` (donde se referencian los `css` y `js`) de la forma en que te explica **Lastimoso** (la cual ya debería aparecer por defecto):

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag     'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

¿Como funciona?

Rails empaqueta todos los archivos `css` y `js` en los respectivos ficheros `application.js` y `application.css.scss` a la hora de compilar, esto se debe a que en `application.css.scss` tienes la anotación `=require_tree`, lo que significa que todos los ficheros css que tengas ya serán referenciados en `application.css.scss` valga la redundancia; por tanto:

1. Elimina todo el código de `index` y deja solo las etiquetas para mostrar tu contenido `<div>`, ya que `index` va a ser *renderizado* en `<%= yield %>`, que se encuentra en `application.html.erb` "tu verdadero layout".

Te recomiendo la [documentación de rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/layouts_and_rendering.html) para que veas cómo funciona esto.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal referenciada la ruta al asset, ya que estas utilizando una ruta absoluta. Tienes que ingresar la ruta relativa al archivo. Para esto, desde la ruta raiz del proyecto, ingresas la ruta de esta forma:

(imaginando que la raiz del proyecto es **hello_world**)

```
<link href="app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.scss" rel="stylesheets" type="text/css">
```

De todos modos, el archivo que quieres incluir no es un CSS puro, sino un SCSS (propio del framework SASS).

Espero te sea de utilidad.
Exitos!

Comment: sigue sin funcionar, ¿Tendrá algo que ver con que sea .scss?

Comment: @FabianOrtiz seguro es eso. Te recomiendo que pruebes con una libreria CSS nativa, para que primero veas si estás levantando correctamente el recurso o no.

Answer (score 0):

Seguramente no te encuentra tu archivo.
Por lo que puedo ver tu proyecto esta en el escritorio, en la carpeta "boomerang"
te recomiendo (si aun no la tienes) que crees dentro de la carpeta boomeran, otra carpeta la cual puedes llamar css. Una ves creada, dentro de ella coloca tu archivo "welcome.scss"

Ahora solo tendrás que agregar lo siguiente:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/welcome.css" type="text/css">
```

Comment: ¿qué debería agregar? no se ve

Answer (score 0):

Un archivo SCSS tiene que ser compilado y no lo deberías pasar directamente a la vista HTML.
Solamente application.css.scss es precompiled por defecto. El resto de archivos tienen que ser incluidos expresamente. Lo podrías hacer con un @import o con require_tree, o modificando config/initializers/assets/ e incluyendo tu activo.

Sugerencia de solución:
1) Dentro de app/assets/stylesheets crea el archivo tuarchivo.scss
2) Pon allí tus estilos
3) En application.css.scss agrega abajo el siguiente código:

```
@import 'tuarchivo';
```

4) En la consola has un rake assets:precompile
5) En tu layout (vista) has la siguiente referencia (usando el helper de Rails)

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag     'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

NOTA: ese último ejemplo de código asume que estás usando Turbolink. Viene por defecto en una applicación de Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Usa el helper [stylesheet_link_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag) en tu vista de la siguiente forma

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'welcome.scss' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Elimina esa línea que pusiste para enlazar, y reemplazala por la siguiente:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'default', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Y cambia la extensión de tu archivo scss de

```
welcome.scss > welcome.css.scss
```

Eso debería bastar.